# Can not wrap text into table

Tags: tables

I am  using EasyThesis template to write my thesis.

I use a file where it contains all the packages I am using. That file contains:

```
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % for writing other that basic characters
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage[font=small,skip=5pt]{caption}
\usepackage{Files/bibspacing}
\usepackage[round, sort&compress, numbers, authoryear]{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{6pt}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{gensymb}


\makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{[#1]\hfill}
\makeatother

\usepackage{mwe}    % loads »blindtext« and »graphicx«
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{verbatim}   % Needed for the "comment" environment to make LaTeX comments
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
\usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes
\let\clipbox\relax % to avoid loading \clipbox

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{x}{>{\Centering}X}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bpchem}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{nicefrac}


\apptocmd{\thebibliography}{\interlinepenalty 10000\relax}{}{}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@caption}{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname:}{}{}
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4.5em}} % default for 3rd arg: 2.3em
\let\l@table\l@figure % as in article.cls
\makeatother

\usepackage{catoptions}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}
\usepackage[titletoc,page,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{paralist}% Package that allows different types of lists such as in paragraph lists.
\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
```

I tried  to draw a table using the command below:

```
\begin{singlespace}
    \begin{table}[t]
        \caption{Types of glycolipid biosurfactants and microorganism producing them followed by their applications. Taken from \cite{reis2013biosurfactants}} % title of Table
        \centering % used for centering table
        \small
        \begin{tabular}{L{3.5cm} L{6.0cm} L{4.0cm}} % centered columns (4 columns)
            \toprule 
            %\hline\hline %inserts double horizontal lines
            %heading
            \textbf{Biosurfactant} & \textbf{Microorganism} & \textbf{Application} \\ %[0.5ex] % inserts table 
            \midrule
            %\hline % inserts single horizontal line
            Rhamnolipids & \emph{{Pseudomonas aeruginosa} (P. aeruginosa)} and \emph{Pseudomonas putida (P. putida)} & Bioremediation   \\ % inserting body of the table
            \addlinespace
            & \emph{Pseudomonas chlororaphis (P. chlororaphis)}             & Biocontrol agent \\
            \addlinespace
            & \emph{Bacillus subtilis (B. subtilis)}           & Antifungal agent \\
            \addlinespace
            & \emph{Renibacterium salmoninarum (R. salmoninarum)}  & Bioremediation   \\ \hline
            Sophorolipids& \emph{Candida bombicola (C. bombicola)} and \emph{Candida apicola (C. apicola)} & Emulsifier, MEOR, alkane dissimilation \\ \hline
            Trehalose lipids & \emph{Rhodococcus} spp. & Bioremediation \\
            \addlinespace
            & \emph{Tsukamurella} sp. and \emph{Arthrobacter} sp. & Antimicrobial agent \\ \hline
            Mannosylerythritol lipids & \emph{Candida antartica (C. antarctica)} & Neuroreceptor antagonist, antimicrobial agent \\
            \addlinespace 
            & \emph{Kurtzmanomyces} sp. & Biomedical application \\ % [1ex] adds vertical space
            \bottomrule
            %\hline %inserts single line
        \end{tabular}
        \label{table:biosurfactant} % is used to refer this table in the text
    \end{table}
\end{singlespace}
```

At first I got a table as I wanted. But after some adding new packages I did not get good table.
I get something like below:

[image]

I could not figure out what might be wrong.
I badly need some help to resolve this.
Hope I can get some help here.

Answer (score 0):

I found the package "pdfsync" gives the problem I was facing. Once I comment out, I get back my table.

Comment: The `pdfsync` package is obsolete and uses a very bad method for implementing synchronization between the TeX file and the PDF output. Activating `-pdfsync=1` in the command line is the method of choice.